# Multipass on a Mac mini M2 failing to launch - no IPV4 address set

Tags: server, ip, macosx, multipass

I have multipass working well on my macbook air M1 - I installed it naively and I've had no problems.

I also had it working well on my Mac mini M2 - in the same way.

It has stopped working, and I've been trying to fix it. The main difference is that I now have a hard-wired link as en0, instead of wi-fi, and I have two ethernet links (en0 to the broadband router and en10 to 5G).

I have installed using:

```
multipass launch -c 2 -d 30G -m 12G -n horus --mount /users/peterbrooks:/mnt/peterbrooks --cloud-init ~peterbrooks/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso --cloud-init '/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/qemu/vault/instances/cloud_config' --network en0  -vvvv
```

cloud_config:

```
#cloud-config

groups:
  - staff

users:
  - name: peterbrooks
    gecos: Peter Brooks
    primary_group: staff
    groups: staff
    home: /home/peterbrooks
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: false
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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 peterbrooks@horus
users:
  - name: ubuntu
    gecos: Ubuntu Default
    primary_group: staff
    groups: staff
    home: /home/ubuntu
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: false
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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 ubuntu@horus


package_upgrade: true

rumcmd:
  - [ uptime  ]

final_message: >
   The system is finally up, after $UPTIME seconds.
```

```
$ multipass list
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
horus                   Unknown           --               Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ounts
$ multipass info horus
Name:           horus
State:          Unknown
IPv4:           --
Release:        --
Image hash:     f885a8e8f62a (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
CPU(s):         --
Load:           --
Disk usage:     --
Memory usage:   --
Mounts:         --
```